# Are the 'IN' and 'OUT' key words compulsory when declaring a PL/SQL procedure/function?

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I am now learning PL/SQL and encountered some misunderstanding like when you declare a procedure, do you have to write the key words 'IN' and 'OUT' when you are indicating the types of the parameters? Because I have seen some declaration of procedure on the Oracle documentation websites. In one case, IN appear in the parameter list

```
PROCEDURE double (
    original    IN  VARCHAR2,
    new_string  OUT VARCHAR2
  ) AS
  BEGIN
   new_string := original || original;
 END;

BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ....
```

And in an other case there is no IN:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE award_bonus (
  emp_id NUMBER, bonus NUMBER) AS
  commission    REAL;
  comm_missing  EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  SELECT ....
```

And also does the key words 'IS' and 'AS' make any difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle PLSQL, there are three parameter modes - `IN`, `OUT` and `IN OUT`. It is not mandatory to specify the `IN` mode. If you don't specify the parameter mode, it is taken as `IN`. For other two, you should specify the mode. In your second example, both parameters are considered `IN`.

You can use either of the `IS` and `AS` keywords. There is no difference.

Check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/procedure.htm) for more details.